MySQL loses connection on accessing some tables
MySQL:
On some specific tables in one database, SELECT or other commands immediately fail  with "2013 Lost connection to server". Sometimes the initial "USE database" fails the same way. Other tables are fine. Other Databases are fine.
Tried DELETE FROM tablename and DROP TABLE tablename and both got the 2013 error immediately.
Trying to get ready to teach January 6 and need to resolve this. Suggestions?
(full-time instructor, newbie DBA)

first you you should check the mysql error file and then you can i  crease the timeouts to a number so hta lost connections will not happen

Thank you nbk ... I thought a log file would be enlightening. However, I dunno where to look. Problem is the IT fellow who set me up two years ago retired and the current folks here (University) don't know DBs.

which operating system are you using, google that with mysql error log and you will get very good qanswers

That's a super suggestion. It's on RedHat, so it's supposed to be in /var/logs/mysqld ... nothing there

Still no resolution. At this point, I would be happy to just DROP that troublesome DB, but that fails too.

have you increased the timeouts in the my.cnf as suggested'?

Sorry, I didn't see your comment. I cannot find the my.cnf file. Is there any way to see it from a MySQL CLI prompt or via MySQLWorkbench?

the first link of google was https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_confined_services/sect-managing_confined_services-mysql-configuration_examples

also you can change the timeout in workbench see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html
